# How to show MapView inside of CardView?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-cardview

I need to use MapView inside of CardView by getting current location.

Your answer is more appreciated. Thanks in advance...

[image]

Comment: Did you try anything? Just put a MapView inside a CardView.

Answer (score 3):

I think this will work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Sum text if you need" />

        <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

`CardView` itself is no more than an ordinary `FrameLayout` with few aesthetic additions. Hence you could inflate anything you want inside of it.

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html) of `CardView`:

> A FrameLayout with a rounded corner background and shadow.

This is just from a layout perspective, to get `MapView` to actually work you'll need a couple of additional setup. Here's a couple of resources in which you could learn a bit more about it:

- [Official guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/) from Google Developers.
- [Tutorial on MapView v2](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjFt-XY-LDLAhUHchQKHXWnD_oQFgg-MAU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vogella.com%2Ftutorials%2FAndroidGoogleMaps%2Farticle.html&usg=AFQjCNE9PiJJYUNOYNayRkahyUHhhqsU0A&sig2=_DhEj97F20liop4qKRVHPw&bvm=bv.116274245,d.ZWU) by Vogella.

Answer (score 1):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Will Be Delievered To" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subtext"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Blah Blah Blah" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Use Fragment over MapView. When you use the Fragment, use either name `MapFragment` or `SupportMapFragment`.

Comment: Thank you, it seems that you can directly embed a Map View inside Card View, but since it automatically requests focus you can't click on the card View it self.